# c++ how do i get a specific value from a specific inherited class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

I'm learning C++ OOP. I don't understand a principle, and I don't know what to google to find an answer.

If I have this:

```
#include <iostream>

class A 
{
    public:
        int a;
        A() : a(1){}
};

class B : virtual public A
{
    public:
        B() {this->a = 2;}
};

class C : virtual public A
{
    public:
        C() {this->a = 3;}
};

class D : public B, public C
{
    public:
        D() {this->a = B::a;}
};

int main()
{
    D test;

    std::cout << test.a << std::endl;
}
```

I expect the output to be `2` since I want the value of the inherited `B` class in the `D` class. It seems to me like the value of the `C` class is taken, because that constructor gets called last and overwrites the `B::a` value, is that right?

How would I go about getting values from the `B` class inside the `D` class?

Comment: `this->a` and `B::a` are the same thing. So `this->a = B::a;` is the same as `this->a = this->a;` which doesn't do anything.

Comment: You can easily check what's going on, stepping through your code line by line with your debugger?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux okay so if a add an int b and int c to the to the D class and assign b = B::a and c = C::a -- they are still both the same value?

Comment: Yes, that's what virtual inheritance means. There is only one underlying `A` subobject.

Comment: Your `class D` contains a single `int`.  There is no "value from the B class" vs "value from the C class".  Only the one `int`, which gets set to `2`, then `3`, then assigned to itself.  Of course the end result is that the one `int` holds a `3`.

Comment: `D` has a single `A` (and so `A::a`), `D::a`/`D::B::A::a`/`B::a`/`C::a` are a single member.

Comment: aah okay thanks @DrewDormann i get it now. I had a misunderstanding about how inheritance worked.

Comment: You didn't say what output you actually got.

Comment: *I had a misunderstanding about how inheritance worked.*  Did you misunderstand **inheritance**, or **virtual inheritance**, or both?